# MSBUild: Copy files with a name based on the original (following a pattern)

Tags: msbuild, copy, design-patterns, rename

I have a set of files inside a folder. They all have a name which matches the pattern DR__.*. I want to copy them to another folder, but removing the DR__ prefix. How can I do this with MSBuild? I used to do it like this using NAnt:

```
<mkdir dir="${ClientPath + '\bin\' + ConfigurationName + '\Parameters'}"/>
<foreach item="File" property="Filename" in="CVParameters">
    <if test="${string::contains(Filename, Client + '_')}">
        <property name="newFilename" value="${ string::substring( Filename, string::last-index-of(Filename, '__') + 2, string::get-length(Filename) - string::last-index-of(Filename, '__') - 2) }"/>
        <copy file="${ Filename  }" tofile="${ ClientPath + '\bin\' + ConfigurationName + '\Parameters\' + newFilename }" overwrite="true"/>
    </if>
</foreach>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get MSBuild Community Task RegexReplace to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177257/cant-get-msbuild-community-task-regexreplace-to-work)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I agree with @Si's solution. But with MSBuild 4.0 you can do it with built in functionality. NAnt script is much clearer than mine. But I will add it as a solution just to show MSBuild 4.0 techniques:

```
    <ItemGroup>
       <CVParameters Include="$(YourBaseDir)\**\DR__*" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="CopyAndRename" 
            Condition="'@(CVParameters)'!=''"
            Outputs="%(CVParameters.Identity)">
         <PropertyGroup>
            <OriginalFileName>%(CVParameters.FileName)%(CVParameters.Extension)</OriginalFileName>          
            <Prefix>DR__</Prefix>
            <PrefixLength>$(Prefix.Length)</PrefixLength>
            <OriginalFileNameLength>$(OriginalFileName.Length)</OriginalFileNameLength>
            <SubstringLength>$([MSBuild]::Subtract($(OriginalFileNameLength),$(PrefixLength)))</SubstringLength>
            <ModifiedFileName>$(OriginalFileName.Substring($(PrefixLength),$(SubstringLength)))</ModifiedFileName>
            <DestinationFullPath>$([System.IO.Path]::Combine($(DestinationDir),$(ModifiedFileName)))</DestinationFullPath>
         </PropertyGroup>                                                                                                                                         

         <Copy SourceFiles="%(CVParameters.FullPath)" 
               DestinationFiles="@(DestinationFullPath)" 
               SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
    </Target>
```

Edit (by OP): To get this working, I had to replace `$(DestinationFullPath)`in `Copy` with `@(DestinationFullPath)`, to match the number of Source and Destination Files. Also, I had to change the prefix to `DR__`, since `DR__.` wouldn't work.

Comment: This answer is more straight forward, got me on the right track and gave me a feel for MSBuild techniques. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Recently I had to solve similar task and I did it using Item's metadata.
Advantages of this solution are:

1. Small build script size.
2. Using standard System.String functions to get modified name.
3. Custom metadata is copying with definition of new items, that based on existing items (e.g. Items `<TempItemsBak Include="@(TempItems-> ... CustomTransform ... )">` will get original item's metadata values so you can use it for further processing)

`<Project DefaultTargets="CopyNoPrefix" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">`

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <InputDir Condition="'$(InputDir)' == '' ">.</InputDir>
    <OutputDir Condition="'$(OutputDir)' == '' ">Output</OutputDir>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <CVParameters Include="$(InputDir)\**\DR__.*" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="CopyNoPrefix">
    <ItemGroup>
      <!-- Items with new name. Use System.String's Remove method to get full file name without prefix -->
      <!-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee886422(v=vs.100).aspx -->
      <TempItems Include="@(CVParameters->'%(Filename)%(Extension)'->Remove(0, 5))">
        <!-- Define metadata based on original item for next step -->
        <OriginalPath>%(Identity)</OriginalPath>
        <SavedRecursiveDir>%(RecursiveDir)</SavedRecursiveDir>
      </TempItems>
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- Use new items along with their metadata for copying -->
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(TempItems->'%(OriginalPath)')" DestinationFiles="@(TempItems->'$(OutputDir)\%(SavedRecursiveDir)%(Identity)')" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you use MSBuild 4.0?  If so, then refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094496/msbuild-getting-property-substring-before-underscore-symbol) (and [MSDN help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx)). Otherwise the RegexReplace task in [MSBuildCommunityTasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) should also work, at the cost of having to support an external tool (so go MSBuild 4.0 if possible).

Another (untested) option is the [TextString](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/3.5.8.0/html/9c5401ed-6f55-089e-3918-2476c186ca66.htm) task in [MSBuildExtensionPack](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/).

Failing those, roll your own task?

Comment: The MSDN Documentation about MSBuild is a bit lacking, so Sergio's answer was more helpful. But I hadn't seen the stuff about Property Functions, so thanks to you too.

Comment: No problems Dario, I agree Sergio's answer was useful! +1 for me 2 :)

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to do something similar to this as well, and ended up with a hacky, but workable solution based on in-line custom tasks.

```
    <UsingTask TaskName="GetNewFileName" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
    <ParameterGroup>
      <OriginalFile ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <PackageVersion ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <NewFile Output="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[

        int versionIndex = OriginalFile.IndexOf(PackageVersion);
        versionIndex = versionIndex < 0 ? OriginalFile.Length : versionIndex;

        NewFile = OriginalFile.Substring(0,versionIndex) + "nupkg";

        ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>

  <UsingTask TaskName="Combine" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
    <ParameterGroup>
      <Path ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <File ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <FullPath Output="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[
      FullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Path, File);
    ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>

<Target Name="AfterCompile" Condition="'$(IsDesktopBuild)'!='true'">

    <ItemGroup>
      <Nuspecs Include="$(SolutionRoot)\$(WorkingBranch)\Nuspec\**\*.nuspec"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- Build nugets -->
    <Message Text="DEBUG: Build nuget packages" />
    <Exec
      WorkingDirectory="$(NuspecsPath)"
            Condition=""
            Command='$(NugetPath) pack "%(Nuspecs.FullPath)" -Version 1.0.0.$(PackageVersion)' />

    <ItemGroup>
      <Nupkgs2 Include="$(NuspecsPath)\**\*.nupkg"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <GetNewFileName OriginalFile="%(Nupkgs2.FileName)%(Nupkgs2.Extension)" PackageVersion="$(PackageVersion)">
      <Output ItemName="RenamedNuPkgs" TaskParameter="NewFile"/>
    </GetNewFileName>

    <Combine File="%(RenamedNuPkgs.Filename)%(RenamedNuPkgs.Extension)" Path="$(NugetRepository)">
      <Output ItemName="PackagesRepository" TaskParameter="FullPath"/>
    </Combine>

    <Message Text="Renamed nuget packages: @(RenamedNuPkgs)"/>
    <Message Text="Repository Renamed nuget packages: @(PackagesRepository)"/>

    <Copy SourceFiles="@(Nupkgs2)" DestinationFiles="@(PackagesRepository)"/>
```

Comment: +1: I didn't know about this alternative. Thanks for sharing!