# string replace over collection of files

Tags: string, msbuild

I am writing an MsBuild script to process config files and do transforms.  I am creating a collection of a .Dev.config files thusly:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <DevConfigFiles Include="..\Source\**\*.Dev.config"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

This works fine.  Doing a  task against %(DevConfigFiles.Identity) gives me what I would expect.  I'd like to take that collection, and create a corresponding collection of the same file names, but with ".Dev.config" replaced with ".config".

I can't figure out the MsBuild syntax to get this done.  What is the best way to accomplish this?

NOTE: I would consider alternative techniques for getting the list of *.config files and the corresponding list of *.Dev.config files, but really I'd like to understand the MsBuild syntax for calling string functions over a collection.  That is the part that is tripping me up.

ANOTHER NOTE: I can't use the %(Extension) metadata in this case because it doesn't remove the ".Dev" portion of the string.  It considers that part of the filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar SO question where the OP wants to take a collection of files and copy them with the name being based on the original string.

[MSBUild: Copy files with a name based on the original (following a pattern)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377917/msbuild-copy-files-with-a-name-based-on-the-original-following-a-pattern)

Comment: Interesting.  I'm guessing something like that could solve my case.  Experimenting...

Comment: @RationalGeek It was a new one for me. Looks a bit like calling functions in xslt. It does mean that you have some of the .net library open to you so you don't have to rush of and write a task to do something simple.